# Running Java from another folder

Tags: java, command-line

I wrote some Java code. I can run it from the target folder as such:

```
java -classpath dependency/j1.jar:dependency/j2.jar package.name.here.className
```

and this is in folder /usr/local/proj/api/target/.

Now, I am trying to call the same java program from ~/usr/local/proj/. So I figure appending the path to the dependency and the package would work:

```
java -classpath /usr/local/proj/api/target/dependency/j1.jar:/usr/local/proj/api/target/dependency/j2.jar /usr/local/proj/api/target/package.name.here.className
```

But instead I am getting an error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class .usr.local.proj.api.target.package.name.here.className
```

I have tried to remove the path on the classname but the same error still exists. Please assist!

EDIT: Few questions: What is the appropriate syntax before the classname? periods or slashes?

Comment: Try to post real code.... don't rename it. It is not simpler to read if renamed and it is possible to introduce bugs related to the renaming

Comment: Try prefixing with ~ i.e. `~/usr/local...`

Comment: @davide lorenzo marino you are right. I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this syntax

```
java -classpath /usr/local/proj/api/target/dependency/j1.jar:/usr/local/proj/api/target/dependency/j2.jar package.name.here.className
```

Comment: java -cp /usr/local/proj/api/target/dependency/j1.jar:/usr/local/proj/api/target/dependency/j2.jar:/usr/local/proj/api/target  package/name/here/className

Comment: Note that it is case sensetive

Comment: Yes. Thanks :P I'm hoping this is a lack of conceptual knowledge and not just a typo.

Comment: I got it to work, FYI, package name should be delimited by periods, not slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Put the target path in the class path.

```
java -classpath /usr/local/proj/api/target:/usr/local/proj/api/target/dependency/j1.jar:/usr/local/proj/api/target/dependency/j2.jar  package.name.here.className
```